# minted environment not working in overleaf

Tags: minted, overleaf

The code it's not working on Overleaf when it comes to minted environment (or mint command) used in a file placed in a subdirectory.
**Note that the very same code works if placed in main directory.**
Tested on Chrome with LaTex,PdfLaTex,XeLaTex and LuaLaTex

You can test the example on [Overleaf site](https://it.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted)  but for your convenience I can add a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
test
\begin{minted}{python}
import numpy as np

def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)

\end{minted}

\mint{html}|<h2>Something <b>here</b></h2>|

\end{document}
```

This will produce only the line "test".

Please note that `\inputminted` works as a charm; I adopted this as a workaround but there are cases in which it is really a nuisance.

Obviously with non trivial projects it is almost impossible for me to keep every file in the same (overleaf) folder.

The log says:(twice, another almost identical is for `\mint`)

```
Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was

probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12 \end{minted}

This could be caused by using -output-directory or -aux-directory 
without setting minted's outputdir, or by using a build tool that 
changes paths in ways minted cannot detect, 
or using frozencache with a missing file.
```

Comment: what error message do you get in the log? Your file (in texlive) runs without error producing [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3SEe.png)

Comment: I edited my question to add the log output and to state clearly that code is working if placed in main directory.

Comment: oh yes overleaf renames its files in interesting ways, it's an overleaf question then I think  you'd be better asking their support

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay so I was having the same issue and the workaround by @yo is correct I believe.
Note that the outputdir depends on where you currently are, so if you're in a folder (say "documents") something as follow should work:

```
\usepackage[outputdir=../]{minted}
```

but if you're for example two layers deep (say "documents/pics") something as follow should work:

```
\usepackage[outputdir=../../]{minted}
```

hope this helps!

This has been further discussed [here](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/251). There are instances where `[outputdir=../../]` is still causing issues when there are different sub-directories. A patch for this issue is developed in the discussion which works with different import packages.

you have to add the below code to the pre-amble,

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% fix for first kind
\xpatchcmd\inputminted
  {#3}
  {\import@path #3}
  {}{\fail}

% fix for second kind
\xpretocmd\minted@pygmentize
  {\restore@IfFileExists} % direct \let\IfFileExists\im@@IfFileExists works too
  {}{\fail}
\def\restore@IfFileExists{%
  \ifx\IfFileExists\@iffileonpath
    \let\IfFileExists\im@@IfFileExists
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

This will successfully work with

```latex
\input{files/file.tex}
```

Hope this will help in similar situations.

Comment: What do "first kind" and "second kind" refer to here?

Comment: @eric basically they're the two incompatibilities between *minted* and *import*. You can read more about this at the link mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 14):

*(Tom from Overleaf Support Team speaking.)*

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of the current setup of Overleaf, sorry for this. The main file should preferably be always placed in the main directory; this is essential in particular for any document that uses external tools, which is the case also for minted.

Comment: Is this something that could be worked around with a change to `minted`?

Comment: Hi Eric! No, I'm afraid this is a given by our setup. We are looking into ways how to remove this burden, and we have ideas how to do that, but none of them is fully backwards-compatible; we know that if we change the ways how we call LaTeX, we'll break something for someone :-/

Comment: In the meantime, is there some way to point an overleaf project to a subdirectory of a larger github project?

Comment: @Eric I'm afraid not directly, sorry for this. But you should be able to do it relaying via a local repo using the git bridge (not the GitHub sync). You would sync the whole GitHub repo with local, and then only sync a subdir with Overleaf.

Comment: To clarify, your suggestion is essentially to use the command line (perhaps `git subtree`?) on my local machine periodically to keep the overleaf "Clone with Git" repo and a subdir of my github repo in sync? I suppose that's doable.

Comment: @Eric That was basically the idea, yes. It's not optimal, but it provides more control than the GitHub sync, which really only synces the whole repo with the project, without any finer control. (Btw, I hate to flood the comments here with unrelated issues as that's not probably a proper thing to do :) , so I suggest you contact us at support@overleaf.com if you have any more questions. Thanks!)

Comment: +1 for trying to address this. Thanks!

Comment: @yo' Hi Tom, it's been almost two years now, can you please tell me if there's a chance this problem will be addressed o must I find a new tool to manage this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @massi Sorry for not helping with this much. However, I just talked to colleagues and they suggested you can use `\usepackage[outputdir=../]{minted}` when compiling in Overleaf, which should help on Overleaf. The problem is, this will not work when compiling outside Overleaf, so it will be necessary to change the options to `minted`. Would this help?

Comment: @yo' Sorry I missed this answer for so long: it's actually working. Could you edit your answer to add this, so to be clear for newcomers? I'm marking this as solved but I'm afraid someone may lose the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It is an actual bug, and the proposed workaround by @yo' using `outputdir` option is not working

I already reported this on github: https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/233

Comment: I won't be that sure until the developer states it's a bug (or e.g. you point out where the bug is and how to fix it). Maybe you're just using the option incorrectly.