# Integrate Python code into Latex

Tags: overleaf, minted, code, python

Hi I would like to display a code with Minted. I have written the following

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{fruity}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Path, PathPatch
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

However, I keep getting an error message that \end{minted} does not work. What have I done wrong?

The Error:

````
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.18 \end{minted}
                 
This could be caused by using -output-directory or -aux-directory 
without setting minted's outputdir, or by using a build tool that 
changes paths in ways minted cannot detect, 
or using frozencache with a missing file.
```
````

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Is this better? All the best

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: you follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146264/i-cant-get-minted-package-to-work-under-ubuntu-pygments-error

Comment: If you struggle to make `minted` work, have a look at `listings`. The quality of the result is similar, and it doesn't require external tools.

Comment: Maybe you are compiling this from a subfolder in Overleaf? If yes then https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531738/minted-environment-not-working-in-overleaf is a duplicate (and the solution is "don't use subfolders", which in general makes things easier).