# Why does an .svg work in some overleaf projects (using beamer) but not others?

Tags: overleaf, svg

I have encountered a frustrating and baffling error while trying to include .svg images generated by Inkscape in a beamer project, compiling on Overleaf.

I have one project in which .svg files are working just fine. In another project I keep getting the dreaded error

> Did you run the export with Inkscape? There's no file
> `./svg-inkscape/ANDgate01_svg-tex.pdf_tex' although` SVGimages/ANDgate01.svg' was found.

I suppose I could just compile the slides in the project where they work, but I have a lot of slides in each project that I'd like to convert from using .png images to .svg and I'm hoping to keep them separated for better organisation.

To try to identify the problem I cut and pasted the code of the main .tex file I'm trying to compile from the project where it works to the project where it doesn't. There is a subdirectory in each project called SVGimages, where the .svg file I'm trying to include sits.

My MWE of the main file is;

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usecolortheme{whale}
  \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
}

\usepackage{Mypackages}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\colorbox{white}{
{\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont \includesvg[height=30mm]{SVGimages/ANDgate01.svg}}
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the content of the Mypackages.sty file is (including all the gory details rather than bare minimum in case they're relevant)

```
\ProvidesPackage{Mypackages}

\usepackage{multimedia} % you probably want to comment this out if not using multimedia elements

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[english]{babel}  % or whatever

\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl} % or whatever

\usepackage{svg}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Or whatever. Note that the encoding and the font should match. If T1
% does not look nice, try deleting the line with the fontenc.
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

I've tried this with several .svg files and it's consistent - so I don't think the problem lies with the graphics files, but rather with the projects. And I can't for the life of me understand how I'm getting an error in one project and not the other when they have the same directory substructure and the exact same code.

Any insight greatly appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT:** This has now been resolved, so for the benefit of anyone else having the same problem (and thanks to Ulrike Fischer in the comments) the problem was different versions of TexLive in the different projects. 2017 (Legacy) and 2022 worked, 2020 (Legacy) did not!

Comment: "(including all the gory details rather than bare minimum in case they're relevant)" you can always make it easier for people to help by removing packages and checking the problem still occurs, but as they are there `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` don't do that overleaf wll be using utf-8 `\usepackage{mathptmx}` very old and does nothing here as you over-ride it with `txfonts` `\usepackage{txfonts}` better to use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` which use newer versions and setup.

Comment: are you using the same texlive version and the same engine in both projects? Did you compare the log-files to find some clue?

Comment: Although you do mention that both projects have the same directory structure, are they actually both in the root of their respective projects? This is important in Overleaf, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531782/ for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the pointers, I'll take your advice.

Comment: @Marijn I did actually try creating different directories (i.e. in root or a sub-directory) and it didn't change the outcome. Good thing to recommend checking though! Thank you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you got it! It turns out TexLive 2017 and 2022 work, but 2020 doesn't! What is this madness!?? Thank you so much for your help, it was driving me nuts!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by incompatible versions of the software, as reported by the OP.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, thank you. I was trying to close the question by accepting my own answer, but SE insisted I wait 24hrs before I could do that. I appreciate someone else handling it before me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including an answer here, so I can close this question

This has now been resolved, so for the benefit of anyone else having the same problem (and thanks to Ulrike Fischer in the comments) the problem was different versions of TexLive in the different projects. 2017 (Legacy) and 2022 worked, 2020 (Legacy) did not!

Comment: You cab accept own answer, Only after then the question will be closed as "solved"...

Comment: @Zarko that was my intent, but SE insisted I had to wait 24 hours before I could accept my own answer.