Gnuplot won't work when called within Overleaf subdirectory
I have a basic file
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
func(x, y) = 0.25*x+y*y;
}
]
  \begin{axis}[set layers,
    title={title},
    view={0}{90},
    xmin=-1, xmax=1, xlabel={$x$},
    ymin=-1, ymax=1, ylabel={$y$},
    xtick={-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1},
    ytick={-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.03)},anchor=north},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.15,0.5)},anchor=north},
    axis on top=false,
    grid=major,
    label style={font=\scriptsize},
    title style={font=\scriptsize,at={(axis description cs:0.5,1.05)},anchor=north}
    ]
    \addplot3[domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1, samples=51,thick,
            contour gnuplot={levels={-1.08963181818182,-0.694963636363636,-0.300295454545455,0.0943727272727273,0.489040909090909,0.883709090909091,1.27837727272727,1.67304545454545,2.06771363636364,2.46238181818182},labels=false}
        ]
        {func(x,y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

If you put this file in a subdirectory on Overleaf it won't draw the contours. Instead returning the error:Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{output_contourtmp0.table} could not be opened.
This is not a problem if it's in the main directory, however I'd like it to be in a subdirectory. I've tried adding the line \graphicspath{ {./subdirectory/} } but this did not affect it. My guess is that file output_contourtmp0.table is in a folder the gnuplot is not able to access. How would I expand gnuplots search? Please bear in mind, I'm using Overleaf.

This is a known limitation in Overleaf, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531782/.
